# Can't vote any question, accept or leave comment

Tags: support, javascript

I can write a question, but I can't vote, accept or leave a comment. Everything was working fine after the last update. It only became a problem moments ago. Say 1 hour before this post but 6 hours ago was fine (I left a comment on "[Bison: Implementing the code after rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691516/bison-implementing-the-code-after-rules)").

I cleared cookies and closed my browser. No luck. Using private mode (or another browser) solves it, but most of the time I like to keep my browsing history.

How might I clear data/solve this problem? I don't want to delete all my data for all sites just to fix this.

I am using Firefox 3.6.8.

-Edit- side effects include not showing upvotes to post I voted on.

-Edit2- it also happens on Super User and Meta Super User. However it doesn't seem to effect Meta Stack Overflow. Gaming.stackexchange.com and other SE are effected as well Geeze. If I am not autologged in then I get the problem. It looks like all i can do is post questions (how funny).

Comment: What does *If I am not autologged in then I get the problem* mean? Why shouldn't you be auto-logged in?

Comment: Arjan: I dont know. It just doesnt and manually logging in gives me said problem. Its fixed by doing what i posted below but unfortunately it has an annoying affect. I tried deleting cookies on SE and SO but that didnt cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clearing site preference not working i decided to delete the last 4 (cookies, cache, active logins, site preference) and it fixed the problem. Hopefully it doesn't clearing this doesnt effect my preference and settings on too many other sites.

Comment: you had bad javascript in your cache for some reason. all you need to do is clear your cache.